# core data delete crash

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I need to update a task before it is deleted. I found when this line `[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` is executed in NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete the app crashes.

```
  case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:{
        Task *task = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self deleleReminderForTask:task];
        [self checkForUpdateForTaskForDelete:task];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
```

crash log:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:]: index (40324416) beyond bounds (1) with userInfo (null)
```

Can anybody help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetched results controller has already been updated so you can't try to get the item from it. Instead you should use the object that is passed as a parameter to the delegate method. You should also check what you're doing with the deleted item is you still have issues.